# Exception when calling a self-executing function in an object literal

Tags: javascript, function, object, this, self-executing-function

I'm trying to set a field's value to a function, then execute it. `this.fetchLocalStorage is not a function` is what I get from running it.

```
var app = {

  busdata: (function(){return this.fetchLocalStorage()})(),

  fetchLocalStorage: function() {
    //fetching
    return "fetching data...";
  }

};
console.log(app.busdata);
```

Note that by not making it a self-executing function, it works, but then it would mean the function is called everytime when I only need to fetch the data one time.

```
busdata: function(){return this.fetchLocalStorage()}
/* ... */
console.log(app.busdata()); //this calls the function every time :(
```

Thought it might a context problem so I tried a couple things with `bind` and `call` but with no luck.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is only bound to the object when you call a method of the object, i.e. `app.someMethod()`. But you're trying to call `fetchLocalStorage()` when you're creating the object, not in a method of the object, so `this` is whatever the outer context is, which is likely the global `window` object.

You can't refer to other properties of the object until after the object has been created. So just call the function normally after you create the object.

```js
var app = {
  fetchLocalStorage: function() {
    //fetching
    return "fetching data...";
  }

};

app.busdata = app.fetchLocalStorage();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your params were on the wrong side of the brace.

```
busdata: (function(){return this.fetchLocalStorage()}() ),
```